# OpenERP customers separation

Tags: odoo

Please I would like to know ho to separate customers in category, since we have two type of customers, the first group should only appear in crm->customers only and vice versa to avoid having a huge list of customers when searching.

My first attempt is to add a tag to different customers to separate them, for example the crm customers have the tag name Mass mailing is it correct to achieve this with tags ?? and my second question how to set default search keyword for example if I click on sales -> customers how to set the default value of search box to for example crmOnly tag thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can use "domain" where ever you want to have a such a separation.

Comment: Could you please give me more details or an example since iam new to OpenERP thank you.

Comment: This document will help you out. https://doc.openerp.com/6.0/developer/2_6_views_events/views/design_element/